# Cast(convert) id to string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to display some record from a database based on their ID. In this case, I would like to display the name (column2) based on the ID (column1) when I do a select query and I get this error.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric

I understand there's something wrong with converting and I was looking for the answer based on this error, but couldn't find anything. A little help?

The Query what I have tried:

```
select part1 
from primar 
where id='1' and id in (select name from primar2)
```

---

The data looks like:

```
ID         Name
===        ===
1          Mike
2          John
3          Mary
4          Anne
5          Jack
```

Later edit: Maybe I explained myself wrong. The `ID` column in the example above belongs to `Table1` and every `ID` have a name associated. In `Table2` there are some other records and among these is the `ID` from `Table1`. I run the SELECT query on `Table2` and I would like to display the name of the ID found in `Table1`, not the ID itself.

Comment: Can you share your SELECT query?

Comment: Are you trying to convert 'Name' to an int? If so, you can't have text in an int field.

Comment: Could you please provide your sql query here what you want ?

Comment: `select part1  from primar where id='1' and id in (select name from primar2)`

Comment: `id` in `primar` is string?  `id` in `primar2` is what?

Comment: rather than discussion, can you display primar and primar2 table's record with column name and the output data with column to more understand.

Comment: Table 1 -- `id cod date    doc_id doc_cod part1`

Table 2 -- `id user_id name`

The `ID` from Table1 is found as part1 in table two and when I run the SELECT query on Table1 I would like to display the name of the `ID`, based on their `ID` from Table1.

Comment: something confused based on your above query and outpu, just add table1 structure with data, table 2 structure with data and output table with column, simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for an inner join;

```
SELECT 
t1.*
,t2.name 
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.ID = t2.user_id
WHERE p.id = '1'
```

This will give you everything from table1 that has a match in table2 and will return the name. Without seeing your schema I've taken a guess at the join field so this may need updating if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

If i am understanding your question, May be you are using wrong field in your where clause. In place of id in you have to use name in

```
select part1 
from primar 
where id=1 and ID in (select Id from primar2)
```

Comment: Maybe I explained myself wrong. The `ID` column in the example above belongs to `Table1` and every `ID` have a name associated. In `Table2` there are some other records and among these is the `ID` from `Table1`. I run the `select` query on `table2` and I would like to display the name of the `ID` found in `Table1`, not the `ID` itself.

Comment: Then you can use this query for id in . Select id from the second table.............. select part1 
from primar 
where id=1 and Id in (select Id from primar2)

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the desired output using **INNER JOIN** . Get rid of the quotes in **id='1'**

```
SELECT 
    p.part1 
FROM 
    primar p INNER JOIN primar2 p2  ON p.Id =p2.Id 
WHERE 
    p.Id =1
```

Answer (score 0):

You must get rid of the quotes in `id = '1'`

```
SELECT part1 FROM primar WHERE id = 1 AND id IN (SELECT id FROM primar2)
```